# Currency converter

Tags: c++, converting, finance

I'm just looking for someone to give a critique of my currency converter.  I want to see if I could clean it up first before dummy-proofing. I know you want to avoid floating types for working with money, so I made a `Cents` class. I'm not fully confident in how I did it, so any pointers on that would be nice.

**Converter.h**

```
        #ifndef CURRENCY_H
        #define CURRENCY_H
        #include <map>

        class Converter {
            private:
                std::map<std::string, double> currency;
                std::map<std::string, std::string> symbol;
            public:
                Converter();
                std::string getSymbol(std::string currency);
                long convertCurrency(std::string c1, std::string c2, long amount);
        };

        #endif
```

**Converter.cpp**

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include "converter.h"

        Converter::Converter(){
            currency["usd-gbp"] = 0.6392;
            currency["usd-cad"] = 1.0478;
            currency["usd-eur"] = 0.7494; 
            currency["usd-jpy"] = 97.821; 
            currency["usd-aud"] = 1.1151;
            currency["usd-chf"] = 0.9232;
            symbol["usd"] = "$";

            currency["gbp-usd"] = 1.5646;
            currency["gbp-cad"] = 1.6393;
            currency["gbp-eur"] = 1.1726;
            currency["gbp-jpy"] = 153.0483;
            currency["gbp-aud"] = 1.7447;
            currency["gbp-chf"] = 1.4443;
            symbol["gbp"] = "£";

            currency["aud-usd"] = 0.8968;
            currency["aud-gbp"] = 0.5732;
            currency["aud-cad"] = 0.9396;
            currency["aud-eur"] = 0.6721;
            currency["aud-jpy"] = 87.7225;
            currency["aud-chf"] = 0.8278;
            symbol["aud"] = "$";


            currency["cad-usd"] = 0.9544;
            currency["cad-gbp"] = 0.61;
            currency["cad-aud"] = 1.4879;
            currency["cad-eur"] = 0.7153;
            currency["cad-jpy"] = 93.3629;
            currency["cad-chf"] = 0.8811;
            symbol["cad"] = "C$";

            currency["eur-usd"] = 1.3343;
            currency["eur-gbp"] = 0.8528;
            currency["eur-aud"] = 1.4879;
            currency["eur-cad"] = 1.398;
            currency["eur-jpy"] = 130.526;
            currency["eur-chf"] = 1.2318;
            symbol["eur"] = "€";

            currency["jpy-usd"] = 0.0102;
            currency["jpy-gbp"] = 0.0065;
            currency["jpy-aud"] = 0.0114;
            currency["jpy-cad"] = 0.0107;
            currency["jpy-eur"] = 0.0077;
            currency["jpy-chf"] = 0.0094;
            symbol["jpy"] = "¥";

            currency["chf-usd"] = 0.0065;
            currency["chf-gbp"] = 0.6924;
            currency["chf-aud"] = 1.2079;
            currency["chf-cad"] = 1.135;
            currency["chf-eur"] = 0.8118;
            currency["chf-jpy"] = 105.9644;
            symbol["chf"] = "CHF ";
        }

        std::string Converter::getSymbol(std::string currency){
            return symbol[currency];
        }

        long Converter::convertCurrency(std::string c1, std::string c2, long amount){
            std::string key = c1 + "-" + c2;
            for(int idx = 0; idx < currency.size(); idx++){
                if(currency.find(key) != currency.end()){
                    double conversion = currency[key]; 
                    conversion *= (double)amount;
                    return (long)conversion;
                } 
            }
        }
```

**Cents.h**

```
        #ifndef MONEY_H
        #define MONEY_H
        #include <iostream>
        #include <iomanip>

        class Cents {
            private:
                long outputCents;
                double inputCents;
            public:
                Cents(long nCents = 0){
                    outputCents = nCents;
                }

                long getLong(){ return outputCents; }

                friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, Cents &cCents){
                    out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << (double)cCents.outputCents/100;
                    return out;
                }

                friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in, Cents &cCents){
                    in >> cCents.inputCents;
                    cCents.inputCents *= 100;
                    cCents.inputCents += 0.5;
                    cCents.outputCents = cCents.inputCents;
                    std::cin.ignore(3, '\n');
                    return in;
                }
        };

        #endif
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cents.h"
#include "converter.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "### Currency Converter ###\n";
    cout << "USD, GBP, CAD, EUR, JPY, AUD, CHF\n";

    string currency1, currency2;

    cout << "-Enter currency to convert from:\n";
    getline(cin, currency1);

    cout << "-Enter currency to convert to:\n";
    getline(cin, currency2);

    Cents amount;
    cout << "-Enter amount:\n";
    cin >> amount;

    Converter convert;
    Cents product = convert.convertCurrency(currency1, currency2, amount.getLong());
    if(product.getLong() > 0){
        cout << convert.getSymbol(currency2) << product << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Currency not found!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You're not using `using namespace std` in your classes, which is good.  However, for `Main.cpp`, it's best to put it inside the function instead of making it global.
- `getSymbol()`'s parameter should be a `const&` since it's not being modified:

  ```
  std::string Converter::getSymbol(std::string const& currency) {}
  ```
- `getLong()` should be `const` since it's an accessor:

  ```
  long getLong() const { return outputCents; }
  ```

  More importantly, it should actually be removed as it's bad for encapsulation (accessors, also mutators, expose the implementation details).  `operator<<` should remain a `friend` so that it can still access `private` members.

  Moreover, I'd have another function modify `outputCents`, then have `operator<<` call it to obtain and display the new value.  `operator<<` shouldn't do extra work, which is why `cCents` must still be passed by value here.  After this change, `cCents` can become a `const&` instead, which is preferred for `operator<<`'s object parameter.
- This form of casting:

  ```
  conversion *= (double)amount;
  ```

  is more C-like.  Prefer the C++ way of casting:

  ```
  conversion *= static_cast<double>(amount);
  ```
- The `for`-loop in `convertCurrency()` is redundant and should be removed.  The `if`-statement already does what's needed to search the map.  In general: loops for STL container classes, such as `std::map`, should use the iterators instead of indices.
- Just a minor point: I'd put `currency1` and `currency2` right next to the `getline()`s:

  ```
  std::cout << "-Enter currency to convert from:\n";
  std::string currency1;
  getline(std::cin, currency1);

  std::cout << "-Enter currency to convert to:\n";
  std::string currency2;
  getline(std::cin, currency2);
  ```

  This is preferred as it keeps the variable's scope narrow, increasing maintenance and readability.

  I'd also rename both input strings to something like `currencyFrom` and `currencyTo`.
- For more user-friendliness, consider an input menu.  This should also require less input-validation as you won't need to rely on the inputted strings *exactly* matching the map's contents.  The menu could be put into a free function, in case a client wants to use it.  Doing so would ensure maintainability, flexibility, and `main()`'s purpose as the *driver* of your program.

  Generally-speaking, no one is *ever* obligated to use your own driver.  Your program should work with any sensible, non-breaking driver.

Comment: Using switch instead of map is a bad idea. You are moving from a data driven system to a hard coded system. The use of the map allows you to use a data driven technique, this allows the system to be updated without modifying the code (and thus recompiling and restesting the code). All you have to do is load the data from an external source into the program rather than having hand coded map initialization.

Comment: Also disagree on your comments about the output operator. Note it is not a member as defined (as friends are not members). Rather than make the output operator not a friend and use an accessor. Prefer to keep it a friend and remove the accessor. get/set methods break encapsulation be exposing implementation details.

Comment: The comment about using std::size in the loop in `currencyConverter()` is also not a good idea. When iterating over a container you should use the iterators. But also not that you missed the fact that the loop is completely redundant and should be removed.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Thanks.  I wasn't paying enough attention to the loop, though I figured `std::size_t` would've been good enough.  As for the map, I didn't think about it that way.  It did seem unneeded at a glance.  I'll make the changes.

Comment: Thank you both for the input, I've made the changes suggested. I'm just curious why the accessor should be removed. How is it that it exposes implementation details and why is this bad? I'm also unsure of how to do an alternative to calling the accessor. To summarize, what I'm doing in main is inputting two strings, inputting the monetary amount into a Cents variable and using the Converter's convertCurrency() function to pass those strings as key values to access the appropriate conversion rate and passing that Cents value to use the conversion rate on. How else can I pass the amount?

Comment: You shouldn't use an accessor *just* because you need to obtain a `private` data member.  Such data is supposed to be kept as close to the class as possible.  So, if you give the interface the option of obtaining or setting (with a mutator) a data member, you're ruining the concept of keeping data private.  For your program, it'd be better to perform a different check that doesn't involve using the accessor.  As for displaying an object, that's why you have `operator<<`.

Comment: About the passing without using an accessor: it looks like you should just pass `amount` to `convertCurrency()`.  As in, the entire object.  Beyond that, I'm not sure how else the process should work, plus I still feel there are more weak points.  You're welcome to open a new question with the updated code so that others may offer more help.

Comment: Another point: Instead of having the user input strings for the currencies, I'd give them a menu instead.  It would look more user-friendly and the input-checking would be simpler.  Although I removed the `enum` suggestion from my answer, I think it would still work here (while still not using a `switch` as corrected here), seeing as you just need the currency types to *identify* which conversion to perform.  I could actually put the menu recommendation into this answer.  If you'd like to go on with this exchange, we could go to chat.